# Is it possible to redirect to another component in response to POST request made in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This gets fired everytime I click submit button based on response I would like to redirect to a certain page or stay on same. I am using node.js as back-end and react for front-end.Also is it better to redirect from frontend or backend

Component/Login.js

```
function myFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ firstname: name, pass }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response === //logic) {
            //redirect to new page
        }
      });
  }
```

routes/api/login.js

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  User.find(
    { firstname: req.body.firstname },
    "password",
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
      }
      let msg;
      if (result.length > 0) {
        if (result[0].password === req.body.pass) {
          msg = "Login Successfull";
        } else {
          msg = "Username and/or Password worng!!";
        }
      } else msg = req.body.firstname + " does not exist";
      res.json(msg);
    }
  );
});
```

Additionally I have this App.js where I use the Router feature

```
<Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Using a SPA with an API backend, I would say **always** handle page navigation, including redirects on the frontend

Comment: I'd recommend redirecting on the front end-- you should be able to navigate to a page imperatively using your application router.

Comment: But how do I do it I have tried res.redirect('/Body') (Body is another component in same folder) it does not work

Comment: It's hard to tell because your code example seems like you're making a fetch from the browser, but then your `then()` logic looks like the handlers in NodeJS/Express.  You also won't likely be able to just redirect to a component by path-- your React app probably has a router that allows you to load views by path, which you can use to redirect on the basis of a specific response.  I'd recommend posting a [mcve], because I'm concerned perhaps you have some issues/incorrect assumptions in your code...

Comment: @AlexanderNied I have edited my code to make more sense . I am just trying to find a way to redirect or render a component after successful POST request

Answer (score 2):

As this is an ajax call, the browser won't react to possible redirect attempts from the backend, e.g. using a 302/303 http status code with `Location` header. It's up to the calling JavaScript application to deal with the response.

Likely the most common way is to navigate to the new page using an abstraction like React Router and its history, e.g.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

// In your component
const history = useHistory();

// When you want to navigate
history.push('/new-route');

// or
history.push({
    pathname: '/new-route',
    state: {
        queryParam1: 'value',
    },
});
```